# Is it possible to do website scripting in C# without using ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, server-side

I apologize if my question has been asked already, but I was unable to format my search in a way that lead to relavent results.

Is it possible to do website scripting in C# without using ASP.NET?

I would like to retain the Apache HTTP server and simply use C# instead of PHP for a project I'm going to be doing. I currently don't have access to a Windows based server and have no interest in switching to one. I was hoping that there might be some way of using C# as the scripting language in a similar fashion to the way PHP is used in the LAMP stack.

Comment: I'm just curious. Why not use Java? Which feature/s of C# are you after?

Comment: Simple language preference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is using Mono. I my self had trouble installing the modules, but more information can be found here.

http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET

Answer (score 1):

I would check out the Mono project. It supports asp.Net MVC 2.0 on Linux.
You can download the IDE MonoDevelop and use it for your development

http://monodevelop.com/